Access Microsoft Defender API to retrieve Security Incidents using Python Office365
I am trying to access the Microsoft Defender Security Incidents data using the Microsoft Graph API in the Office365-REST-Python-Client library. But the result isn't returning any records. What am I doing wrong?
# from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
from office365.graph_client import GraphClient
 
username = "matt@example.com"
password = "my password"
 
# user_credentials = UserCredential(username, password)
client = GraphClient.with_username_and_password(
    'tenant ID', 'client ID', username, password
) 
result = client.security.incidents.get_all().execute_query()
 
print(result)

Result:
[]

